# How to draw Mundell-Fleming Trilemma in Latex (using TikZ)?

Tags: tikz-pgf

community

I'm trying to reproduce this graphic representation using TikZ, but I am not having success. If someone can reproduce, it will help a lot in my thesis.

[image: Mundell-Fleming Trilemma]

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE community. We will surely give you an answer that you will like however it is always better to learn sooner or later. But are you only interested in the triangle with the labels?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome new contributor! This is a starting point for you.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,line width=2.5pt,
n/.style={text=white,fill=#1,midway},
nodes={font=\bfseries\sffamily}]
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{.8} 
\def\r{3} 
\colorlet{colorA}{red}
\colorlet{colorB}{teal}
\colorlet{colorC}{green!50!black}

\path[nodes={align=center}]
(0,0) node{Pick one\\side of\\the triangle}
(90:\r) node (C) {Free capital\\mobility}       
(210:\r) node (B) {Exchange\\rate\\management}
(-30:\r) node (A) {Monetary\\autonomy}
;
\draw[<->,colorC] (A)--(B) node[n=colorC,below=1mm]{C};
\draw[<->,colorA] (B)--(C) node[n=colorA,above left=1mm]{A};
\draw[<->,colorB] (C)--(A) node[n=colorB,above right=1mm]{B};
\path (current bounding box.north west)+(0,5mm) node[right,scale=1.2] {The policy trilemma};
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This implementation is great.

Comment: @KleytondaCosta You are welcome! and recommended posting a minimal working example (to show what you have tried) for the next questions ^^